# How to set character encoding in BeanIO?

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, bean-io

I have a Fixed Length stream. I want to set encoding to Windows-1252 or latin1.

How can I do that?

Via XML would be better, but if code is the only way, it is ok too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Character encoding is controlled external to the BeanIO library using the basic Java I/O APIs. Here's a quick and dirty example showing the setup for writing:

```
Charset charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"); // ISO Latin Alphabet No. 1
OutputStream ostream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // or other OutputStream
Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(ostream, charset);

BeanWriter beanWriter = streamFactory.createWriter(nameOfMappedStream, writer);

// write beans here...

writer.flush();
```

Reading should be similar.